# Which ruby+rails+mongodb version combo should I use for web development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

Are there are issues using a specific ruby version with rails 3.0.3?
Can you guys suggest a stable working combo compatible among ruby+rails+mongodb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go with rails 3.0.3, ruby 1.9.2 and mongodb 1.6.5